# Como ejecutar Http en una wen con Https

Tags: html, http

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda.

Tengo una sección en mi web, donde quiero mostrar una radio. Para ello tengo el siguiente fragmento

```
<audio id="stream" controls preload="none" autoplay style="width: 400px;">
<source src="http://192.99.18.164:9562/;" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script>
var audio = document.getElementById('stream');
audio.volume = 0.5;
</script>
```

Pero resulta ser que mi web al tener SSL, chrome me bloquea la solicitud y no puedo escuchar la radio. Hay alguna forma de poder mostrar la radio sin tener que migrar la transmision a un servidor que ofrezca servicios con Https.

Comment: Desafortunadamente no creo que haya nada que puedas hacer. Desde [Chrome 88](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html), todo el [mixed content](https://web.dev/what-is-mixed-content/) es bloqueado y no es algo que puedas cambiar. Tu página no puede cambiar las preferencias de seguridad en los navegadores de los usuarios.

Comment: Esque aquí surge mi duda, esta web que estoy haciendo es mediante wordpress y hay un plugin de pago que promete hacer eso, entonces no sería de fiar según lo que tu me dices

Comment: Mmmm, suena raro ese plugin, pero no es imposible. Probablemente lo que haga sea obtener el contenido que deseas a través de un intermediario que sí provea una conexión segura. Es como que yo ponga a alguien en el medio que me vaya a buscar los datos de manera insegura, pero que ese intermediario me los dé a mi de forma segura. Probablemente por eso el pago, hay que pagarle al intermediario (es decir, al servicio que busca tus datos).

Comment: Lo otro que puede hacer el plugin en tu servidor, es, en lugar de dejarle al cliente la obtención de los datos, que el servidor los obtenga mediante php y se los de al cliente de manera segura. Pero ya estoy teorizando de las diferentes maneras que puede estar implementado. Cualquier servidor puede hacer la petición sin problemas, lo que si no puede pasar es le pidas a un navegador que traiga contenido inseguro, de una página que fue servida de manera segura.

Comment: Puedo hacer yo directamente eso mediante php? Esa es mi duda para ver si puedo solucionar el problema sin recurrir al plugin de pago

Comment: De poder hacerlo, puedes. Yo personalmente ni programo en php ni uso wordpress, por tanto, no soy el más indicado para ayudarte con los detalles de implementación. Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarte. De cualquier manera  con una simple búsqueda encontré el plugin [SSL Insecure Content Fixer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) ¿Es ese el plugin que me hablas? No parece de paga. ¿Lo probaste? Tiene muy buenas reviews.